# Connecting to Python XML RPC from the Mac

Tags: python, macos, xml-rpc

I wrote an XML RPC server in python and a simple Test Client for it in python. The Server runs on a linux box. I tested it by running the python client on the same linux machine and it works.

I then tried to run the python client on a Mac and i get the following error

```
socket.error: (61, 'Connection Refused')
```

I can ping and ssh into the linux machine from the Mac. So i dont think its a configuration or  firewall error.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

The code for the client is as below:

```
import xmlrpclib

s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://143.252.249.141:8000')

print s.GetUsers()

print s.system.listMethods()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Connection Refused" means the connection was **REFUSED** - the machine `143.252.249.141` is up, and in the network, but is not accepting connections on port `8000` - it is actively *refusing* them.

So maybe the server software isn't running on the server? Or is running in another port? Or is bound to a different IP address?

Comment: So it turns out the IP that you specify in the server has to be the one in the client.

I had localhost in the server and then was using the ip on to connect from the other machine!